# Using material ui tabs with react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a project in react/typescript.  I have a react router that looks like this

```js
const Root = () => (
    <>
      <NavBar/>
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/timer" component={TimerPage} />
      </Router>
    </>
);
```

And I have a material-ui appbar that looks like this

```js
export default function NavBar() {
  return (
      <div>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Tabs>
              <Tab label="Timer" to="/timer" component={TimerPage}  />
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
      </div>
  );
}
```

There are a few issues - first the 'to' in Tab doesn't compile.  Secondly, how do I make these two components work together, given they do very similar things?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using material-UI tabs with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279676/using-material-ui-tabs-with-react)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to navigate to another page, wrap your tab component, let react-router handle with the navigation and navigate using react-router history,

```
 <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs 
     example">
   <div onClick={() => history.push("/timer")}>
        <Tab   label="Timer" />
    </div>
  </Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/timer" component={TimerPage} />
</Router>
```

`Route` should be inside `Switch`. Also, if you write `path="/"` this means that whatever page you will visit will still go to "home" page. This is because react-router does something like "least" checking of routes. So, if you had defined path `"/images"`, before `"/images/1"`, both will route you to `"/images"`. Instead you could change the order of these paths, or add `exact` keyword before the first one.

Take a look at example below.

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/timer" component={TimerPage} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

or

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/timer" component={TimerPage} />
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

As for your second issue, you should put your `AppBar` (or `div` or any container) inside `Router` and assign `Link` to `component` property of `Tab`:

```
<Router>
    <AppBar position="static">
          <Tabs>
              <Tab label="Timer" to="/timer" component={Link}  />
          </Tabs>
    </AppBar>
</Router>
```

Keep in mind that `Link` component is imported from react-router and not from @mui.